# How to check whether multiple BackgroundWorkers have compled their task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have three BackgroundWorkers that each query db for data. I want to how it would be possible to check whether all three BackgroundWorkers have completed their work, so that i can execute some logic ?

This is what i have done so far, but it flags an error saying -
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

```
public void WaitForThreadsToComplete(Object _Item) 
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessElements(_Item.Id)),
        Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessCompulsoryField(_Item.Id)),
        Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessFieldRange(_Item.Id)));

    // my logic here
}
```

Comment: How you are creating `BackgroundWorkers`?  could you please share your code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why do you need to mix tasks and `BackgroundWorker` at all? `Task`-based API and async/await obsolete. Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2011/10/10/from-backgroundworker-to-tpl-to-async.aspx) and [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Task.Run%20vs%20BackgroundWorker).

Answer (score 2):

Take another look at your error:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Then do what the error message says to do:

```
public async Task WaitForThreadsToCompleteAsync(Object _Item) 
{
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessElements(_Item.Id)),
    Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessCompulsoryField(_Item.Id)),
    Task.Run(() => InitiateBackgroundProcessFieldRange(_Item.Id)));

  // my logic here
}
```

I also added an `Async` suffix to your method name so it follows the [TAP guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RunWorkerCompleted` Event to identify this.

Try This:

```
BackgroundWorker bg1 = new BackgroundWorker();      
bg1.DoWork+=bg1_DoWork;    
bg1.RunWorkerAsync();  //start the worker
bg1.RunWorkerCompleted+=bg1_RunWorkerCompleted;


private void bg1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    /*Worker started - do something*/
}
private void bg1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    /*worker ended - do something*/
}
```

Comment: You have to apply `DoWork` on that also.